# Count only frame opened outside of terminal?

Tags: frames, emacsclient

I want to enforce only one GUI instance for Emacs, so I want to check if at least one GUI frame is open or not (i.e. the frame that is open with `emacsclient -c`), and ignore the ones opened in Terminal. How do I do that? I already tried `visible-frame-list` function but this seems to count all frames.

Comment: frame-list returns a list of all live frames and frame-visible-p returns if a frame is visible

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `framep` function to determine the type of each frame.  It returns a symbol describing the type of the frame: `t` for terminal, `x` for X window, `w32` for MS windows, `ns` for Mac/GNUstep, and `pc` for a direct-write MS-DOS frame.

Once you have this you could count the number of (say) X Window frames with something like `(length (seq-filter (lambda (f) (eq (framep f) 'x)) (frame-list)))`, or for a function that returns t if there is an X Window frame otherwise nil, use `(seq-some (lambda (f) (eq (framep f) 'x)) (frame-list))`.  There are many other variations as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `display-graphic-p` function:

> display-graphic-p is a compiled Lisp function in `frame.el'.
>
> (display-graphic-p &optional DISPLAY)
>
> Return non-nil if DISPLAY is a graphic display.
>   Graphical displays are those which are capable of displaying several
>   frames and several different fonts at once.  This is true for displays
>   that use a window system such as X, and false for text-only terminals.
>   DISPLAY can be a display name, a frame, or nil (meaning the selected
>   frame's display).